# twisted module: I can't work my program from the ip of raspberry pi

Tags: python, twisted

I was trying to make a program with the twisted module so as to control a led from the ip of my raspberry pi. I'm new in this and now im trying to learn. I have called my program "lights.py" and in the same folder with this file, i have a folder called "lampwww" in which there is a index.html file with this code inside:

Lights

a href="http://ip of raspberry pi/API?light=on"> Turn On  | a href="http://ip of raspberry pi/API?light=off"> Turn Off

So when i open index.html and click turn on or turn off it doesn't work, also when i just open the ip of raspberry pi at the browser (i have seen the ip using ifconfig), it doesn't show me what i have writen inside the index.html, it just show me the text "it works"...

Here is the code of my program. What am i doing wrong? what am i missing? thanks in advance!

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.static import File    
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pin = 17
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

class lampAPI(Resource):

   def render_GET(self, request):
        if 'light' in request.args:
            if request.args['light'][0] == "off":
                GPIO.output(pin, False)
                return " light off "
            if request.args['light'][0] == "on":
                GPIO.output(pin, True)
                return " light on "

root = File("/lampwww")
root.putChild("API", lampAPI())
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(8080, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP server you wrote listens on port 8080.  You need to use `http://raspberrypi:8080/` as the beginning of any URL.